# Sending Mishloach Manos

Tags: minhag, purim, mishloach-manot

All Jews are obligated to send mishloach manos on Purim (based on Esther 9:22).

If I plan to send mishloach manos to a friend via the mail, must I send them to where the package will arrive on Purim or should I send them on Purim, where they would receive the package after?

Comment: Is meshloach monos by mail actualy counted? What if there's a non Jew dealing with it? And anyway I'd imagine that it has to be sent and received during Purim

Comment: real shlichus is not required. the main idea is that it gets there. i believe that it must arrive on purim, as that is the point, that the receiving party get the food, but i am lazy to look it up